# Magento custom payment notification

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, payment-gateway

I have successfully integrated a custom payment solution for magento with a lot of help from this tutorial http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/

I am at the last stage of notifying the website if a payment has been successful or not.

I have a PaymentController.php file below but am not sure how to link this to the payment gateway notification.

The payment gateway provide a notification to the server via an HTTP GET request, letting you know if a payment was accepted or declined. This is below

http://www.websitedomain.co.uk/mygateway/payment/response?Operator=&SessionID=&Note=&Tariff=&Status=&Mobile=

The code for the payment controller where I need to enter the code is below

```
class Myname_Mygateway_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
// The redirect action is triggered when someone places an order
public function redirectAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','mygateway',array('template' => 'mygateway/redirect.phtml'));
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
}

// The response action is triggered when your gateway sends back a response after processing the customer's payment
public function responseAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        /*
        /* Your gateway's code to make sure the reponse you
        /* just got is from the gatway and not from some weirdo.
        /* This generally has some checksum or other checks,
        /* and is provided by the gateway.
        /* For now, we assume that the gateway's response is valid
        */

        $validated = true;
        $orderId = ''; // Generally sent by gateway

        if($validated) {
            // Payment was successful, so update the order's state, send order email and move to the success page
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
            $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Gateway has authorized the payment.');

            $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            $order->setEmailSent(true);

            $order->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();

            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
        }
        else {
            // There is a problem in the response we got
            $this->cancelAction();
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure'=>true));
        }
    }
    else
        Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('');
}

// The cancel action is triggered when an order is to be cancelled
public function cancelAction() {
    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
        if($order->getId()) {
            // Flag the order as 'cancelled' and save it
            $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Gateway has declined the payment.')->save();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have the line  `$validated = true;`
Here you have to enter your own conditions if the payment has been validated.

So if this is the response from the payment gateway use the variables in the response
http://www.websitedomain.co.uk/mygateway/payment/response?Operator=&SessionID=&Note=&Tariff=&Status=&Mobile=

for example

```
if ( $_GET('Status') == 'Paid' ){
$validated = true;
}
```

You have to read the payment gateway documentation on info for their codes. For example the Status variable can have values like "Paid", "Pending", "Expired" or "1", "2", "3". Depends on the gateway.